# How to setup adjustsFontSizeToFit to scale text in nested Text components in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

Trying to get a text which is a currency (**52 0000,00** USD) where I want the ticker to have a different font weight than the amount. I want the text to fill the whole screen width using adjustsFontSizeToFit.

When using the same Text and fontWeight it works but using nested `<Text>` scales down the font size a lot more than necessary?

You can try yourself here:

https://snack.expo.io/Hk1-K3RwG

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text, View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Constants } from 'expo';

export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
      
        <Text style={[styles.text, {fontWeight: '900'}]} adjustsFontSizeToFit numberOfLines={1}>
          {'245,000.00'}{'\u00a0'}USD
        </Text>
        
        <Text style={styles.text} adjustsFontSizeToFit numberOfLines={1}>
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: '900'}}>{'245,000.00'}</Text>
          {'\u00a0'}
          <Text style={{ fontWeight: '400'}}>USD</Text>
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
    backgroundColor: '#ecf0f1',
  },
  text: {
    height: 50,
    fontSize: 60,
    padding: 0,
    margin: 0,
    width: '100%',
    textAlign: 'center',
  },
});
```

[image: Image of the problem]